# Why omissions of prepositions are done in English?

Tags: prepositions

> I am listening **(to)** the music.
>
> To revenge **(for)** a murdered brother.
>
> **(As)** A system-level simulator based on the realistic modeling of fiber optic communication systems, it possesses a powerful new simulation environment and a truly hierarchical definition of components and systems.

Some people just omit them. Why?

Comment: In regards to your first one, _I am listening the music_ sounds completely ungrammatical to me. ("I am _hearing_ the music" would be fine, but not "I am _listening_ the music".)

Comment: The second is also ungrammatical. The verb is **avenge**. When we avenge, we seek revenge.

Comment: The third is an appositive noun phrase.  *A collapsible, lightweight **stove, it** is ideal for hiking.*   We could introduce that noun phrase with **as**, but that does not mean it has been omitted.

Comment: We don't omit prepositions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are three entirely different cases, not examples of a single phenomenon.

The first one appears to be a mistake: I would guess it was said by somebody whose native language was not Englisn. *Listen* requires *to*.

The second one uses the (comparatively rare) **verb** *revenge*, which (unlike the noun *revenge*) does not require a preposition. i.e. it is transitive. (Historically, *avenge* was far more common than *revenge* as a verb, but my impression is that *revenge* has become more common).

In the third case, it is simply using a different construction (an [**absolute**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) phrase) from the one you are thinking of (an adverbial phrase). The meaning is hardly any different.

A very useful comment from TRomano:
The third is an appositive noun phrase. A collapsible, lightweight **stove, it** is ideal for hiking. We could introduce that noun phrase with **as**, but that does not mean it has been omitted.

Comment: I have seen "revenge on" being used.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what *some* people do with prepositions in their speech, *to listen to* is a fixed collocation and it needs no explanation why it is so.

The same is with the *noun* revenge, which requires the preposition *for*:

> The attack was in revenge *for* the death of two prisoners.

As for the verb revenge, it doesn't require a preposition before the direct object:

> He wants to revenge the murder of his brother.

As for the third example, it falls totally apart with the previous two and obviously is the subject of a separate question.

Comment: I might suggest that in the context, it is sooner being than as that was omitted.What do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant exactly what Colin Fine pointed out as a different construction to be discussed in another thread.

Comment: It is sooner being than as that was omitted?I could not understand.

Comment: *I listened **for** the music as I neared the concert grounds.*

Comment: Thanks, Alan! Indeed, listen for (here, the spell-checker warns of a wrong preposition) something/someone is idiomatic expression meaning to try to hear someone or something, not to pay attention to the sound of something which is the meaning of the verb "listen" collocating with the preposition to.

Answer (score -1):

"As for the verb revenge, it doesn't require a preposition before the direct object:

He wants to revenge the murder of his brother."

Incorrect.  The word in the sentence above should be 'avenge'.

"He wants to avenge the murder of his brother."

If you want to use the word 'revenge' in the sentence above, it would need to be formed differently.

Example:

He wants to take revenge for the murder of his brother. 
He seeks revenge for his brother's murder.
Revenge is his goal.

Comment: "Take revenge for a perceived wrong" is the definition of both the verbs "avenge" and "revenge". Also, you may want to see [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Avenge_vs_Revenge).

Comment: He wants to revenge "on" the murder.

Comment: Rompey and Singh, I see what you are saying, but as a native NAmE speaker, I must disagree in usage.  In the usage I know and hear, "avenge" is a verb.  "Revenge" is a noun.  And one does not avenge "on" a murder.  One can take revenge 'for' a murder. Or one can avenge a murder.

Comment: @Rompey - While technically you're right, I think Kaye has a point, too. Notice how [AH](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=revenge) lists the verbal form of _revenge_ as `Archaic`. [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/revenge) labels it as `chiefly literary`. So, yes, it **can** be used as a verb, but many modern readers might find such usages a bit quirky, and feel that _avenge_ might be a better fit.